# MS Sync Center vs Robocopy batch job

Tags: backup, rsync, batch, robocopy

I have a number of videos from our marketing department on a local machine for video editing which need to be transferred periodically to a few different NAS's.  Is there any appreciable difference between MS Sync Center and Robocopy?

Would Sync Center be more of a set it and forget it vs Robocopy being a batch?  These are just large video files for sequential write after the video is edited.

Comment: Neither choice is a set it and forget. Robocopy is better if you can make a good set of bat files and have a good log folder. If you can not, still stay away from the Sync Center. Find a script writer resource to write the .bat files.

Comment: Even though this is not in system admin, biggest part of answer is need to verify no issues after getting it 100% setup.At first,once every two weeks, then once every two months, etc. but no matter what time frames are used, follow up talking with users and checking logs and verify everything is ok.

Comment: Why should I avoid Sync Center?

Comment: Sync center is designed for set & forget. If there environment was stable (no new users or pcs, no change in NAS and no network issues) then it would be good.  The ability to respond to errors or upcoming events (This Friday we are making XXX change to the network or nas.) Great how do you modify setup? Scripts and robocopy much easier to adjust.  Biggest flaw is not hearing about a problem until something has gone critical.